# Attribute Error when using functions in classes

Tags: python, class, tkinter

I have been tryig to create a Tic Tac Toe game with tkinter. I am not very familiar with classes, but I tried to use them as practice. For whatever reason, an error is always called at "self.sq1.config()". The error is 
Attribute Error:'buttons' object has no attribute 'sq1'

Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import*
root=Tk()
root.title("Alpha NO")
game = [[0,0,0],
        [0,0,0],
        [0,0,0]]


class buttons:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.sq1 = Button(root, height="5", width="11", text="", command=self.change(0, 0))
        self.sq1.grid(row="0", column="0")

    def change(self,r,c):
        game[r][c] = "1"
        self.sq1.config(text="X")

a = buttons(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Change `command=self.change(0, 0)` to `command=lambda: self.change(0, 0)`... Your problem is due to your command executing on `__init__` instead of waiting for button press. Because the command executes before `self.sq1` is assigned on `__init__` here then you get the error that `self.sq1` does not exist yet. To fix this you simply need to use a lambda statement.

Comment: You are referencing `self.sq1` *during* definition of the variable. Something like `x = x + 1` where `x` isn't defined elsewhere in the namespace

Comment: Expanding on Mike's comment, the `lambda` will allow a function to be assigned to a variable or keyword arg in this case, without executing. That way, when the button is pressed, `command` is called, and thus, the `lambda` function